# How can I make a Deck of Many Things?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, crafting

I would like to make a [*Deck of Many Things*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/deck-of-many-things) but I can't figure out, how. My GM said if I could figure it out they would let me do it. I know my character has to be 17th level to even start on it but that's as far as I've made it. Does anyone know the step-by-step instructions?

Comment: Did your GM tell you to figure it out, or tell you that *your PC* had to figure it out?

Comment: You (or your DM) may also be interested in [this *AD&D* question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71716/8610)

Answer (score 19):

### Ask Your GM

There are no official rules for crafting magic items. The *Dungeon Master's Guide* provides one optional rule that your GM may want to use.

### Using the DMG rules:

> ... To start, a character must have a formula that describes the construction of the item. Their character must also be a spellcaster with spell slots and must be able to cast any spells that the item can produce. Moreover, the character must meet a level minimum determined by the item's rarity

1. You'll need a formula for the crafting

   - This is likely going to require a quest or something of the sort with a legendary item like the Deck of Many Things.
2. You'll need the *wish* spell since The Moon card produces that spell.

   - Your GM may require other spells to account for the spell-like effects of some of the other cards (such as knowing *imprisonment* for Donjon).
3. As you state, level 17 is the minimum for crafting Legendary magic items
4. Time and money

   - From there you just need to spend the time and gold pieces required which with these rules would be 500,000 gp and 20,000 days (you can likely split this up among helpers with the same prerequisites)

*Xanathar's Guide to Everything* provides some alternative downtime rules including for crafting magic items.

### Using the XGtE rules:

> To start with, a character needs a formula for a magic item in order to create it. The formula is like a recipe. It lists the materials needed and steps required to make the item.
>
> An item invariably requires an exotic material to complete it. This material can range from the skin of a yeti to a vial of water taken from a whirlpool on the Elemental Plane of Water. Finding that material should take place as part of an adventure.
>
> The Magic Item Ingredients table suggests the challenge rating of a creature that the characters need to face to acquire the materials for an item.

1. You'll need a formula for the crafting

   - This is the same as in the DMG rules.
2. Defeat of a powerful creature (suggestion of CR 19+ for legendary magic items)

   - The required materials may be a part of the creature's anatomy, or be present in an area guarded by one such creature.

> Note that facing a creature does not necessarily mean that the characters must collect items from its corpse. Rather, the creature might guard a location or a resource that the characters need access to.

3. Time and money

   - This requirement is substantially less than that in the DMG: 50 workweeks (500 days) and 100,000 gp.

It is worth noting that there is no level requirement for the XGtE rules.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81079/discussion-on-answer-by-david-coffron-how-can-i-make-a-deck-of-many-things).

Answer (score 2):

### The GM decides if and how this works

5e is a bit vague when it comes to magic items in general, and particularly when it comes to crafting them.

*Xanathar's Guide to Everything* has some rules for the crafting of magic items as a downtime activity on pages 128-129. Basically, in addition to time, money, and tool/skill proficiency, you need two things: a formula for the creation of the magic item, and an exotic material.

The details of both are left to the GM. In practical terms as a player, this means that you won't be crafting anything unless your GM wants you to be able to. Outside of whatever the GM decides, there is no way to craft a magic item. If you are really set on it, start searching for answers in character and let the GM decide the rest.

Comment: Might add that most of XGtE is optional material. Only the points on rules clarifications are not.